# The indeterminate form problem

Tags: soft-question

How to solve for $a$

$a\pm k$(k being any real number other $0$)=$\frac{a}{a}=a^2=a$ Find $a$ ( $k$ is any real number other than $0$

The only solution I could think of is $$\frac{0}{0}$$

But does it belong to real numbers and is my solution correct?

Comment: There is *no* real solution to $a\pm k = \frac aa=a=a^2, k\neq 0$

Comment: Is $\frac{0}{0}$ real?

Comment: no, division by 0 isn't defined for reals numbers (to preserve their field structure)

Comment: @user153283 No, $\frac 00$ is undefined.  Also, $0\pm k \neq 0, \text{ when } k\neq 0$.

Comment: @user153283 If $k=0$ the solution would be $a=1$. Elsewhere there is no solution.

Comment: Outside the real numbers? just saying..

Answer (score 2):

$$a \pm k = \ldots = a \implies a \pm k - a = 0 \implies \pm k = 0$$

Comment: What if $k$ is given to be non zero?

Comment: @user153283 Then there is no solution.